# How are numeric types managed in fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I have an issue that hopefully would not affect my numerical calculations in Fortran 90.

The thing is that I have an array declared as

```
Real(r8), Allocatable              :: matKBody(:)
```

By my hand, initializing such array I done it like

```
allocate(matKBody(1:Nk), STAT=ierr)
If (ierr /= 0) Stop
matKBody(:) = ( 0.0_r8, 0.0_r8)
```

which is a way to initialize a complex array. I noticed this error but I was surprised
that it doesn't matter if I initialize such array in this way or using the 'correct' statement:

```
matKBody(:) = 0.0_r8
... 
... ! Do some stuff with the array
...
Deallocate( matKBody, STAT=ierr )
If (ierr /= 0) Stop
```

If I print both arrays they give me the correct initialization , i.e. both initialize
real numbers.

Why fortran (or the compiler) is not aware of such kind of things?
(I used ifort for compilation).

Comment: You need to allocate an allocatable array using the `ALLOCATE()` function.

Comment: What error? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I added a more concise treatment of the used array.
The error is that the array is declared as real, but
I can initialized as a complex, or real number and the
question is why this is valid.

Comment: The complex literal has to be converted  to real then assigned.  I'd assume the conversion simply takes the real part -- but why would you want to do that?

Comment: so you're saying that as long as I put a valid type of number, for instance a integer, this array will return a real...?

Comment: Exactly, fortran does (or allows) automatic conversion among the basic intrinsic types.

Comment: so the strongest statement here is the declaration section, good to know! I guess I have expended too much with python recently.

Answer (score 1):

Full example:

```
program test_convert

use, intrinsic :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV

Real(real64), Allocatable              :: matKBody(:)

allocate (matKBody (1:10) )
matKBody(:) = ( 0.0_real64, 0.0_real64)

end program test_convert
```

Compiled with gfortran with options: `-O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace`

Output from gfortran:

```
matKBody(:) = ( 0.0_real64, 0.0_real64)
              1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from COMPLEX(8) to REAL(8) at (1)
```

So some compiler are "aware" of such things and will tell you about them if you request it to.

As discussed in the comments, Fortran provides automatic conversion between types upon assignment.   So this is not an error, but gfortran at least will provide a warning so that the programmer can check whether they intended the conversion.   You can suppress the warning and state your intent to cause a conversion via:

```
matKBody(:) = real ( ( 0.0_real64, 0.0_real64), real64 )
```

(This is just an example, since writing `= 0.0_real64` is so much simpler for this particular assignment.)